# Can the coordinating conjunction ”and” conjoin two different time sequences?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

The following sentence is from a ”A study in scarlet” by Arthur Conan Doyle:

> If you are unable to come I shall give you fuller details, **and** would esteem it a great kindness if you would favour me with your opinion.

As per my question title I wonder if **and** can conjoin two main clauses with different time sequences. For me **I shall give** and I **would esteem** are different unless they can be both regarded like some kind of future.

Comment: Read *I shall give you fuller details* **and** *I would esteem it a great...* The *and*, in my opinion, connects the sentences excluding the pronoun *I.* It can conjoin two timely different clauses. *I like you and will do anything for you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjunction *and* can certainly conjoin two different clauses occurring at two different times.

> I like you and will do anything for you.

As I said, the conjunction connects the sentences excluding the pronoun *I* in this context.

This said, your sentence can be broken this way...

> ...I shall give you fuller details. **And**
>  I would esteem it a...